# PayPal Sandbox -Amount different to actual purchase price?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, e-commerce, paypal-sandbox

I have setup a Personal and Business account using Sandbox. When I run a test purchase for, for example, £46.92, under the Business account balance it says £45.12 - Where has the £1.80 gone? 
Is it automatically deducted for paypal fee's or something?

Or is there something wrong with my setup?

(I am using the WP eCommerce plugin for WordPress)

Thanks

Comment: PayPal shouldn't charge more than £1.86. Isn't there a detailed record showing more info about each incoming payment?

Comment: @Pekka he said "£1.80" is gone. If so it may be the paypal fee?

Comment: @Vasanthan you're right! Not sure how I misunderstood that. Yeah, it's probably the fee then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this PayPal Fee calculator](http://www.clothnappytree.com/ppcalculator/), the UK fee for a  £46.92 transaction is £1.86. So yeah, it's probably the fee that has been deducted.

In my PayPal account, I can see the fees deducted in the detail view:

[image]

you should be able to see the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't say any fee deductions under my sandbox account, it just says the full amount taken.

Comment: @Huw you don't have a detail view for each transaction? Maybe that is sandbox specific

Comment: I think it must be Sandbox specific, which is a shame as I would love 100 % confirmation that it is correct.